# Reduce an array of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects

```
[
{
 job_code: '123',
 application: 'Tree',
 permission_name: 'AP_SEARCH'
},
{
 job_code: '123',
 application: 'Dog',
 permission_name: 'ALL_FA_SEARCH'
},
{
 job_code: '123',
 application: 'Tree',
 permission_name: 'AP_DOWNLOAD'
}
]
```

And I need the format like

```
[
{ name: 'Tree', permissions: ['AP_SEARCH', AP_DOWNLOAD'] },
{ name: 'Dog', permissions: 'ALL_FA_SEARCH' },
]
```

My code is

```
const allowedApplications = rdsData.map((key) => ({ name: key.application, 
permissions: key.permission_name }));
console.log(rdsData);
```

But it Output like below

```
[
{ name: 'Tree', permissions: 'AP_SEARCH' },
{ name: 'Dog', permissions: 'ALL_FA_SEARCH' },
{ name: 'Tree', permissions: 'AP_DOWNLOAD' }
]
```

Please Help. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

You could group by `application` by using an object.

```js
const
    data = [{ job_code: '123', application: 'Tree', permission_name: 'AP_SEARCH' }, { job_code: '123', application: 'Dog', permission_name: 'ALL_FA_SEARCH' }, { job_code: '123', application: 'Tree', permission_name: 'AP_DOWNLOAD' }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { application: name, permission_name }) => {
        r[name] ??= { name, permissions: [] };
        r[name].permissions.push(permission_name);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: [
  {
    application: 'Tree',
    permission_name: [ 'AP_SEARCH', 'AP_DOWNLOAD' ]
  },
  { application: 'Dog', permission_name: 'ALL_FA_SEARCH' }
]
This is the result of yours. But need 'All_FA_SEARCH' also inside an array

Comment: it looks different than the wanted. anway, please see edit.

Comment: My I know why did u put ??=

Comment: it is a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), like `a ??= []`, a short form of `a = a || []`.

Comment: Hello Nina Scholz. I just figured out. In the response it should be "name" and "permissions" instead "application" and "permission_name". Please update the answer if you can

Comment: please see edit.